# sql query with ORDERBY and ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The following query

```
SELECT JOB_TYPE, CLASS, JOB_RUN_START, JOB_RUN_FINISH, JOB_STATUS, JOB_PID FROM 
(SELECT * FROM ARCHIVE_JOBS ORDERBY JOB_RUN_START ASC ) WHERE ROWNUM <=6;
```

yields to an error:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Anybody know why?

Comment: No Asenar he is missing a space between order and by

Answer (score 2):

It's `order by` and you missed aliasing your subquery. I used `X` as alias name

```
SELECT JOB_TYPE, CLASS, JOB_RUN_START, JOB_RUN_FINISH, JOB_STATUS, JOB_PID 
FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM ARCHIVE_JOBS 
   ORDER BY JOB_RUN_START ASC
) X
WHERE ROWNUM <=6;
```

Comment: Asenar & juergen - thanks both you. the query worked. I am just a beginner here.

Comment: @Asenar: There is no need to remind users to accept answer. That is totally up to them and if you had looked in the OPs profile you would have noticed that he already accepted 2 other answers. So he knows how that works.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `ORDERBY` by `ORDER BY`

ORDERBY is not a keyword, so it's considered by mysql as in the `FROM` part of the query (i.e. a table), and table list should be separated by `,`

Comment: you are correct @Alfons